# I removed the drum from washing machine and there was still water in the drum. Should there be?

Tags: washer

Maytag Bravo Xl front loading wash machine. Took the drum out and there is water in it. Should there be and how to get it out?

Comment: It's normal _to an extent_. Does the water level rise after a day or two?

Comment: True... I would have hoped that they disconnected the machine, or at least turned off the wall valves, before opening it up, but they might not have and a valve in the machine could have a slow leak. Which would be another problem needing repair.

Answer (score 3):

This is a normal condition.

It is common for some amount of water to run back into the machine after the spin cycle. The manufacturer just lets that pool under the inner basket. It generally does no harm, and folks don't realize it's happening until they need to move or disassemble the machine

As far as getting rid of it: syphoning would work, if you have a suitable piece of tubing. Or throw towels in until they have soaked it up. Or use something as a scoop and bail it out. Or use a vacuum that is certified for use with water (don't even think about using a standard household vacuum). Or disassemble and dump it somewhere. Or some combination of any of the above. It's just water; treat it like a puddle anywhere else that you want to remove.

Comment: Or inexpensive [hand pump](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B075C3NNZF) if a siphon won't work (maybe not enough head difference?).